# On NiFi how to differentiate messages coming from two different Kakfa?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have two different applications named A1 and A2. Each application has its own Kakfa server. Messages coming from these two KAKFA servers (brokers) goes to NiFi.

Each Kakfa has different topic names and based on that I can differentiate messages coming from Kakfa. But apart from Kafka's topic name are there any other ways in NiFi to differentiate messages coming from two different Kakfa? Are their any NiFi processor which checks the topic name and then decide the next route to take?

Thanks a lot.
regards,
Yeshwant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using NiFi's Kafka processors (ConsumeKafka/ConsumeKafkaRecord) to receive messages from Kafka, they will output the messages in the form of `FlowFiles`. They carry one attribute called `kafka.topic` which will have the name of the topic the message came from.

To route the messages based on the topic name, you can use `RouteOnAttribute` processor. Say for example, you have two topics `topicA` & `topicB`. Then you have to configure the RouteOnAttribute processor like this:

[image]

[image]

Then connect the relationship `topic-a` & `topic-b` to separate flows based on your requirement. If you're adding more Kafka sources, all you have to do is, update `RouteOnAttribute` with one more dynamic relationship. Ex: `topic-c : ${kafka.topic:equals('topicC')}`

Comment: Thanks Sivaprasanna. I tried your solution and worked out well. Once I differentiates the various sources of Kafka I need to send Restful HTTP get and post request. I used InvokeHTTP processor but there is no property in configuration screen to write POST body message. Do I need to use processor like UpdateAttribute or ReplaceText and then send it to AttributesToJSON? And after that send it to InvokeHTTP?

Comment: Bryan had answered this in your other question. That's how `InvokeHTTP` works.

Comment: What if I want to create routing based on some attribute value? Since message is of JSON format I first used EvaluateJSONPath. It has attribute 'engine'. Then I connected this processor to RouteOnAttribute. I added new route 'topicD' which has value ${.engine:equals('XJERA')} But in 'putFile" processor I don't see any data coming in. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You can't provide the JSON path expression in place of NiFi expression language.You have to add a dynamic property to `EvaluateJSONPath` where the key can be anything and value is JSON path expression and in `RouteOnAttribute` you have to provide the key. Take a look at this: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/118237/how-to-use-apache-nifi-evaluatejsonpath-for-json-t.html

Answer (score 2):

Another resolution. You can use the [`CryptographicHashContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.CryptographicHashContent/index.html) processor for this purpose. You get unique hashcode of the content and based on this you can determine your message.

*Note:* The [`HashContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HashContent/index.html) processor is marked as deprecated as of Apache NiFi 1.8.0 because of a non-standard legacy implementation and may be removed in upcoming versions.

Comment: I updated this answer to point to the `CryptographicHashContent` processor which replaces the _deprecated_ `HashContent`. I'm not sure how this solution answers the question, but at least the referenced processor is up to date.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wrote "HashContent" cause I spend a lot of time on our work project which have version 1.4.0 in production :) Just forgot about it)

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful comment.